# strange JS syntax, what does it mean?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I recently came across this strange JavaScript code:

```
export type ImageSource = {
  id: string,
  URI: string,
  thumbnail: string,
  title: ?string,
  description: ?string
}

type Props = {
  images: Array<ImageSource>,
  onPressImage?: Function,
  topMargin?: number,
  closeText?: string,
  infoTitleStyles?: Animated.View.style,
  infoDescriptionStyles?: Animated.View.style,
  enableTilt?: boolean
}
```

If I understand it correctly, string is a data type, but can someone explain, what is the difference between string and ?string.

Also, what does the following line of code mean:

```
topMargin?: number,
```

I've got it from a sample react-native app, I'm assuming, it signifies an optional property, but I can't find any explanation when googling for it.

Comment: It looks like typescript and it means that the field is optional, effectively: `number` or `undefined` https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#optional-properties

Comment: could be flow too https://flow.org/

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably either [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org) or [Flow](https://flow.org). `topMargin?: number` represents an [optional parameter](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/primitives/#toc-optional-function-parameters) and `title: ?string` represents [maybe types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/primitives/#toc-maybe-types).

Comment: Wondering, if this is a common thing, why it's not being referred to in any of the react-native documentation?

Comment: TypeScript is a strongly typed, object oriented, compiled language. Mostly people code in Javascript, and if it was flow; flow is a static typechecker for javascript, sort of like a plugin, so it doesn't make sense to add it to documentation.